# when i was reading Core.Java.Volume.I,i can't understand the meaning of this sentence

Tags: java

When I was reading Core.Java.Volume.I, I can't understand the meaning of this:

> "Be careful to ensure that the code in a critical section is not
>   bypassed by throwing an exception. If an exception is thrown before
>   the end of the section,the finally clause will relinquish the lock,
>   but the object may be in a damaged state."

How can I ensure that? Isn't the code in a critical section must to be bypassed when throwing an exception?

Comment: Might help to see the code that quote is discussing.... don't you think?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this pseudocode:

```
Patient patient = service.getPatient(name);
hospitalEquipment.lock();
try {
  patient.pauseLifeSupport();
  // some code causing an exception
  patient.resumeLifeSupport();
} finally {
  hospitalEquipment.unlock();
}
```

In this pseudocode the exception causes a "critical section" to be bypassed, namely resuming life-support. You could potentially fix this by moving the call to `resumeLifeSupport()` inside the `finally` block or have some emergency behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Add your own code in `finally` section to ensure that the object is in a safe state. How exactly to do that? Depends on the object and the state.